# What is the benefit of using a 10MΩ resistor in parallel with a current shunt?

Tags: current, multimeter, shunt

I am reading the Operators Manual for the Fluke 8588A Reference DMM and came across this:

> The DCI Ext Shunt function provides a calculated current reading for a specified current shunt by measuring the voltage across the shunt. If Shunt Corrections are OFF, the displayed current is calculated from I = V/R where R is the resistance of the shunt. If Corrections are ON, the displayed current is calculated using the parallel resistance of the shunt and the 10 MΩ input impedance of the DCI Ext Shunt function.

What "corrections" are made when using a 10 MΩ impedance in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about your setup.

*A DMM also has internal resistance (10Meg e.g).*

This resistance is connected in parallel when measuring the shunt. Therefore, the effective resistance "shown" to the current is changed - and the raw I = V/R_shunt equation gives an error. The feature uses the equation I = V / ( R_Shunt || R_DMM ) instead to correct for this error - See the Image.

This matters more, if your shunt is of bigger value (Measuring nA, pA instead of A, mA).

**See:**

[image]

Where R_M is your DMM internal resistance (In Volts-Mode) and R_S is your Shunt.

**Please ignore the "Coil" Label**